# How to design an ActionListener class in Java?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

**NOTE:** I'm learning about *Clean Code*, *Design Patterns* and *Object Oriented Programming* so please keep that in mind when answering.

I've got a window with bunch of `JButtons` and a `TextField` on the top. Here's the Window class in its separate file:

```
// Window.java
public class Window {
    JTextField textField;
    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;
    ...
}
```

**Here's what I'd like:**

When I press `button1` I want the `textField` to display "1", when I press `button2` to display "2", etc. So here's the ActionListener class in a separate file and this is sort of what I want it to do:

```
//TextInputActionListener.java
public class TextInputActionListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == button1) {
            textField.setText("1");
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == button 2) {
            textField.setText("2");
        }
    }
}
```

Now obviously this wont work, so my question is **how should I define this class?**

- **Should I declare it as an inner class of `Window`?**
- **Should I not bother to create a separate class for it?** (I could just make the `Window` class implement `ActionListener` and that would solve the problem)

**NOTE:** As you can see the question is not how to do it but rather, how to do it in a way that supports Object Oriented Design.

Comment: #1) Extend Action instead of implementing ActionListener. #2) You can either define the action in the Window class or pass in the parameters that it will operate on. Either approach is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First of all I'd like to thank everybody who answered the question. Without you I would've not figured it out. Each one of you gave me a piece of the puzzle.*

My initial problems were:

1. `TextInputListener` class needs access to `buttonX`.
2. `TextInputListener` class needs access to `textField`.

In the TextInputListener class I figured that it doesn't really need access to the buttons, it only has to know if `e.getSource()` equals `button`. So I created methods in the `Window` class that takes an `ActionEvent` as a parameter (like `e`), compares it to `buttonX` and returns returns the answer.

```
//Window.java
...
boolean isButton0(ActionEvent e) {
    return e.getSource() == buttons[0];
}
boolean isButton1(ActionEvent e) {
    return e.getSource() == buttons[1];
}
...
```

**PROBLEM 1 SOLVED:**

So now I'm one step closer. I can determine whether `button1`, `button2`.. was pressed, without declaring the buttons public or without returning it by a "getter" method like `getButton1()`.

```
// TextInputListener.java
public class TextInputListener implements ActionListener {
    Window window;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (window.isButton0(e)) {
            //textField.setText("0")
        } else if (window.isButton1(e)) {
            //textField.setText("1")
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

(*TextInputListener.java and Window.java are in the same package so I was able to declare the methods package-private.*)

**PROBLEM 2 SOLVED:**

Once again `TextInputListener` didn't really need `textField` (as a variable) it just needed to set its text. So I created another package-private method `setOutputText(String text)` for setting the text. Here's the code:

```
// Window.java
public class Window {
    TextField textField;
    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;
    ...
    void setText(String text) {
        textField.setText(text);
    }
}

// TextInputListener.java
public class TextInputListener implements ActionListener {
    Window window;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (window.isButton0(e)) {
            window.setText("0");
        } else if (window.isButton1(e)) {
            window.setText("1");
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

**PUTTING EVERYTHING TOGETHER:**

The only thing that's left now is to let each instance of the class to know about each other. In `TextInputListener` class I added the following code:

```
public void listenTo(Window window) {
        this.window = window;
    }
```

In the Window class I had to add the `ActionListener` to each button, so I added the following code:

```
public void setActionListener(ActionListener l) {
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i].addActionListener(l);
        }
    }
```

That's basically it! In main set everything up and it's working. Here's the (almost) full final code:

```
// MyApp.java
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Window myWindow = new Window();
        TextInputListener myTextInputListener = new TextInputListener();

        myWindow.setActionListener(myTextInputListener);
        myTextInputListener.listenTo(myWindow);
    }
}

// Window.java
public class Window {
    TextField textField;
    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;
    ...
    void setText(String text) {
        textField.setText(text);
    }
    public void setActionListener(ActionListener l) {
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i].addActionListener(l);
        }
    }
}

// TextInputListener.java
public class TextInputListener implements ActionListener {
    Window window;

    public void listenTo(Window window) {
        this.window = window;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (window.isButton0(e)) {
            window.setText("0");
        } else if (window.isButton1(e)) {
            window.setText("1");
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With your current structure, the `Window` class can implement `ActionListener` because it is responsible for listening to events on its view. An inner class would also be acceptable but could lead to more cluttered code. You should be watchful of excessive separation of concerns. You should only really separate your code in terms of the Model, the View, and the Controller.

Definitely check out the [MVC](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm) design pattern.

Comment: Haven't studied the MVC pattern yet, but it was very useful. Thank you for pointing it out for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Since listener classes often need access to fields of GUI classes (like your `Window`) using inner classes for listeners is a good idea.

Of course it is not forbidden that `Window` implements `ActionListener` but you then expose implementation details in the public API and you should think if you want that.

Note that lambdas and method handles of Java 8 give you even more possibilities to write listener code:

```
class Window {
    JTextField textField;
    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;


    Window()
    {
        button1.addActionListener(event -> textField.setText("1"));
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on this problem :

- Should `ActionListener` implementation be declared as an inner class of Window? - I would not. This is because inner classes are used when there is a piece of functionality that is closely associated with the state of the containing class. For e.g. an `Iterator<E>` implementation can be written as an inner class of `Collection<E>` implementation. In this case the `Iterator` implementation has access to the private data members of the `Collection` implementation. Another example is the [Builder pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225207/why-should-a-builder-be-an-inner-class-instead-of-in-its-own-class-file).Inner classes have access to the private members of the parent class and hence should be used with care.
- Should you create a separate class for it - Yes, and you should declare it in a separate file at minimum required access levels. You would not want to make the `Window` class implement `ActionListener` - simply because this would make the Window class responsible to handle events for **all** it's containing controls - violation of the separation of concerns (Single Responsibility Principle). So imagine the code you would be writing - it would be fraught with a long list of `if` conditions or a switch case to identify the source of the event. This obviously implies that if you add a new control to the window class you increase the length of the `if` or `switch` block. Declaring the action listener in a separate class allows for separations of concerns and also helps testability.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer, but if I should declare the actionlistener class in a separate file, how can I access the buttons and modify the textfield? If you could maybe edit your answer and provide me with some example code that would be awesome! :)

Comment: Create a constructor for your TextInputActionListener) class, and pass the needed parameters to it: `button.addActionListener( new  TextInputActionListener(textField) );`